# C# xPath is not a valid expression

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I'm fairly new to xPaths and am having a problem trying to get an element from a table.

I'd like to get the price from this table which is located in the first row, third column.

[image: Table in question]

The xPath I was trying to use is as follows: ("((//div[@id='calc-result']//table)/tr/td[3]");

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I think it should look like this: `"//div[@id='calc-result']//table/tr/td[3]"`, that being said, without the HTML DOM it will be difficult for us to tell. Other than that, browsers such as Chrome support searching through XPath, so you can use that feature to test your expressions.

Comment: Hey npinti thanks for the fast response. Unfortunately after trying your suggestion still getting invalid expression.

Comment: What if you try `"//div[@id='calc-result']/table/tr/td[3]"`

Comment: You add an extra opening bracket `((//div...`...Don't use those parentheses at all - they are redundant. Suggested `"//div[@id='calc-result']//table/tr/td[3]"` should not lead to Syntax error. Check if you implemented it correctly

Comment: I've got the parentheses because I'm passing the xpath as a string to a method that waits for the element just in case the web page is still loading, so they are required. The xpath is just incorrect for some reason... An xpath that isn't giving me an invalid response is this: ("((//div[@id='calc-result']//table)[2]//th)[1]//td[3]"); Still can't find the element though.

Comment: Andersson your suggestion doesn't throw an error, however it still cannot locate the element.

Comment: If element cannot be found try to wait for presence of element or check whether table is located inside frame/iframe

Comment: I am waiting for the presence of the element already and it isn't in an iframe.

Comment: Ok lads got it working. Used ("(//td[@tabindex='2'])[1]//span");  and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked: ("(//td[@tabindex='2'])[1]//span")

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath( ("//div[@id='calc-result']//table/tr/td[3]")));
```

Comment: Didn't work, can't locate element.

Figured it out though, this worked: ("(//td[@tabindex='2'])[1]//span")